# Get url favicon with Jquery

Tags: jquery, favicon, prepend

I found a script which allows to display favicons based on an url over here: [andreaslagerkvist](http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/favicons/)

Its a pretty simple script, there is a good example but when I copy/paste the example it doesn't seem to work..Please take a look at this demo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUyzC/)

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something in the script?

Comment: Where do you assign the function to your div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never called the plugin, you only defined it.

**Plugin Definition**

```
jQuery.fn.favicons = function (conf) {
    var config = jQuery.extend({
        insert:        'appendTo', 
        defaultIco: 'favicon.png'
    }, conf);

    return this.each(function () {
        jQuery('a[href^="http://"]', this).each(function () {
            var link        = jQuery(this);
            var faviconURL    = link.attr('href').replace(/^(http:\/\/[^\/]+).*$/, '$1') + '/favicon.ico';
            var faviconIMG    = jQuery('<img src="' + config.defaultIco + '" alt="" />')[config.insert](link);
            var extImg        = new Image();

            extImg.src = faviconURL;

            if (extImg.complete) {
                faviconIMG.attr('src', faviconURL);
            }
            else {
                extImg.onload = function () {
                    faviconIMG.attr('src', faviconURL);
                };
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**Plugin Invocation**

```
jQuery('#jquery-favicons-example').favicons({insert: 'insertBefore'});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUyzC/1/).

Comment: Thank you so much:) (I never heard of insertBefore..)

Comment: @PeeHaa, who is your comment directed at and to what end?

Comment: It was directed @ OP. Since the examples to get it to work are right above the code in jsfiddle :-)